# How to map elements from a List, using cycle <c:forEach> with values from <h:inputText>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am a novice with these technologies and i need help. 
I try to cycle through all elements from a list and for each one to have inputText box. I manage to cycle them successfully (UI looks nice) but i have difficulties to write the Java code which map each item with the value from inputText box. I need this because i will have to save the id, inputted value and some other things in other object in the database, thanks for the help in advance!

Here is the code from .xhtml file:

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel2" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <c:forEach items="${filterTypeBean.listTextFilterTypes()}"
                        var="inputBoxes">
                        <h:outputText value="${inputBoxes.filterTypeName}"
                            style="width: 100px; white-space: normal; border: 3px" />
                        <h:inputText value="??????????" />
                    </c:forEach>
```

Managed bean code:

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "filterTypeBean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class FilterTypeBean implements Serializable {

    // .....

    public TFilterType gettFilterType() {
        return tFilterType;
    }

    public void settFilterType(TFilterType tFilterType) {
        this.tFilterType = tFilterType;
    }

   //..


public List<TFilterType> listTextFilterTypes() {
            EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
            Query q = em.createQuery("select u from FilterType");
            List<TFilterType> resultList = q.getResultList();
            return resultList;
        }

        // I don't have the part with the mapping...

    }
```

Comment: '@ManagedBean(name = "filterTypeBean")
    @SessionScoped
    public class FilterTypeBean implements Serializable{
    
    .....
    
    public List<TFilterType> listTextFilterTypes() {
      EntityManager em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
      Query q = em.createQuery("select u from FilterType");
      List<TFilterType> resultList = q.getResultList();
      return resultList;
     }'
 
I don't have the part with the mapping...

Comment: Any ideas about how the method for <h:inputText value=??? /> should look like and how to take mapped ID of inputBoxes (inputBoxes.id) and the inserted value and insert them in a new table in the database? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I have getter and setter methods, i added also them above, thanks for editing.